# 意味的に pitch accent

Tags: pitch-accent

I always hear 意味: いみ{HL} and 意味的に: いみてきに{LHHHH}. And I'm under the impression 的に heibanfies words.

I think I hear 意味的に いみてきに{HLLLL} [here](https://youtu.be/9ZTNlaN0VEk?t=532), and wonder why. This guy seems to be a native speaking professional Japanese teacher, which makes it all the more puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

This is いみてきに＼は, you are just misinterpreting it. Learners often hear ghost accents when speakers add "tension" into their voice, like is being done here.

Basically, since there is so much tension coming from the emphasis he is putting on the phrase (i.e., he starts the phrase very very high in his vocal range, with his vocal chords tensed), it would be physically difficult for him to exactly maintain the same pitch throughout the word, let alone do a clean LHHHHL (and it would sound *very* weird if he did somehow manage to do this so high in his vocal range), so it naturally goes down in a few spots before the accent, but they do not sound like accents, it's just release of tension.

Comment: So he does an いみてきには{HHHHHL} as opposed to いみてきには{LHHHHL}?

Comment: @EddieKal Probably the notation shows nothing about rising: [音の「上がり目」は、それぞれの単語に固有の情報ではなく、あくまで「単語を単独で発音したとき」や「強調の意図があるとき」などに現れてくるものであり、語のアクセントを示すのにあたって、必ずしも不可欠なものではないためです。](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/accent/faq/1.html)

Comment: @sundowner Oh I see! Thank you.

Comment: @EddieKal - Whit it’s true that the lack of the initial rise doesn’t alter the phonetic quality of the word, いみてきには{HHHHHL} does sound dialectal. It happens to be the accent in Kansai-ben.